# Cannot figure out a cURL command POST

Tags: post, curl

I have been trying to figure out how to use cURL to grab the information from a web domain https://www.dnsleaktest.com/

There are two buttons on this site, one is Standard test and the other is Extended test.. I would like to have cURL output all the data from either or.

This is the output of a regular cURL command..

```
<form action="results.html" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" class="standard" name="standard" value="Standard test"></input>
  <input type="submit" class="enhanced" name="enhanced" value="Extended test"></input>
```

Any cURL gurus able to give me advice on this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first open up "Developer Tools" in Chrome, and perform the action. If you watch the "Network tab" you should be able to figure out which thing is the actual request that the web browser will send:

Then use the information in here to send the same request in curl:

```
curl -X POST https://www.dnsleaktest.com/results.html \
    -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "standard=Standard Test"
```

You'll have to identify what is important in the request and then include that information in the curl command.

Comment: The argument to `-d` should be in the form `name=value`, so it should be `-d "standard=Standard Test"`

Comment: I appreciate both the answers, jpadams provided an excellent answer but it still isn't quite there and here's why...(on the next comment)

Comment: curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
<div class="container_12"><div class="grid_12 results"><h2><span id="result_title">Test in progress...<img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" style="margin-left:10px;"></span></h2><pre class="progress">Query round Progress... Servers found<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img width=0 height=0 src="https://5y7ci99pc7.dnsleaktest.com">$